# Paginate blog with AngularJS Mongoose Express

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, mongoose

I would like to paginate my blog with AngularJS / Bootstrap client side and Mongoose / Express server side. Actually I make a call to my rest API which return every blogposts i've got in my DB:

Server side **lib/controllers/blogs.js**

```
/**
 * List of Blogs
 */
exports.all = function(req, res) {
  Blog.find().sort('-created').populate('creator', 'username').exec(function(err, blogs) {
    if (err) {
      res.json(500, err);
    } else {
      res.json(blogs);
    }
  });
};
```

I would like to just get those which are on the actual page, but I don't really know how to do it as I'm calling GET /api/blogs.

Server side **lib/config/routes.js**

```
  var blogs = require('../controllers/blogs');
  app.get('/api/blogs', auth.ensureAuthenticated, blogs.all);
```

Maybe someone could help me to do it ? I'm totally new to Node.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your posts are not a lot, you can simply use `.skip()` and `.limit()` in your query:

```
/**
 * List of Blogs
 */
exports.all = function(req, res) {
  Blog.find().sort('-created').skip(req.body.skip).limit(req.body.limit).populate('creator', 'username').exec(function(err, blogs) {
    if (err) {
      res.json(500, err);
    } else {
      res.json(blogs);
    }
  });
};
```

The above code is not so good in performance when your collection grows. `.skip()` counts all documents that you are skipping.
Instead you can use range query like:

```
/**
 * List of Blogs
 */
exports.all = function(req, res) {
  Blog.find({_id: {$gt: req.body.lastId}).sort('-created').limit(req.body.limit).populate('creator', 'username').exec(function(err, blogs) {
    if (err) {
      res.json(500, err);
    } else {
      res.json(blogs);
    }
  });
};
```

The last code is better in performance (even if you have thousands posts). But you only have next and previous page and you can't directly jump into n-th page.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do, is paginate your data, meaning that you need to return only the first X items (i.e. blog posts) from your DB, at a time. Something like this:

```
Blog.find().sort('-created').skip(10).limit(10).populate('creator','username').exec(function(err, blogs) {
    if (err) {
      res.json(500, err);
    } else {
      res.json(blogs);
    }
});
```

This will return the posts ranging from #11 - #20.

Comment: So if i put variables instead of 10, sent from the client side, it should works ?

Comment: Yes, it should. But, Forad Nosrati Habibi's response to your question is more efficient.